# Configure SonarQube on Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube-scan

I have SonarQube and Jenkins dockerized(They're running on different containers); sonar is running on localhost:9000 and Jenkins is running on localhost:8080. I configured the Sonar credentials(with acces Token) on Jenkins, but i when run SonarScanner I'm getting the following error by SonarScaner on Jenkins:

```
ERROR: SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached
INFO: ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
INFO: Total time: 0.358s
INFO: Final Memory: 4M/119M
INFO: ----------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute SonarQube
ERROR: Caused by: Fail to get bootstrap index from server
ERROR: Caused by: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000
ERROR: Caused by: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Docker:
[image]

How could i solve this, or make that both containers communicate between each others?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `127.0.0.1` as the IP address because that's the IP of the local container. You need to use the IP of the host.

I wrote an [article](https://funnelgarden.com/sonarqube-jenkins-docker/) on how to setup a Docker container of Jenkins and SonarQube to talk to each other that explains the setup.