# How to connect jenkins with sonarqube for android code review?

Tags: android, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

I am new to docker and Jenkins. How to connect the Jenkins with Sonarqube to check the code review of the Android project. I tried but getting a below error. I need to run Sonarqube in Jenkins pipeline script.

com.android.build.gradle.api.ApkVariant.getCompileLibraries()Ljava/util/Collection;

Comment: Would you mind posting your pipeline code?

Comment: Have u set-up sonarqube server and configured jenkins to point to it?

Comment: Also, all the dependencies and plugins are added in android project?

Comment: + sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=android123 -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=574f2fcc2ac9e6b7c2d408b58a1a3e8bf0504e6f
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/android@tmp/durable-9681746a/script.sh: 2: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/android@tmp/durable-9681746a/script.sh: sonar-scanner: not found

Comment: i faced this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49908708/configure-sonarqube-on-jenkins